What is this band of reflectivity return caused by?
On the reflectivity scan from TIAH on 20240624 at 2058z, a couple of thunderstorm cells pop up to the West of the radar site. Just beyond these cells, a narrow North-South band of reflectivity return (~20dBZ) shows up, and moves to the West. What could cause this return?


It is dust being picked up by a gust front.
Dust can reflect radio waves, creating a band of reflectivity marking the location of the gust front
